# How to split log file in using glog(github.com/golang/glog)

Tags: go, glog

Because my server may run for a long time, the log file will be too large.Is there any way to cut logs according to size or time?

Comment: ```mkdir -p log && go run main.go -log_dir=log``` and it will be  auto split in  dir log

Comment: It's amazing! How does it split the log file, size ?

Comment: @Para I test to add 350,000 lines of logs, but it can't be split (Is it not enough?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I found a way to split logs.
Using third party libraries.(ex:`https://github.com/natefinch/lumberjack`)

Comment: The easiest way is to modify the fields `MaxSize` of the file `glog_file.go`

Answer (score 0):

Since you worry about a large log file, try conditional logging or occassional logging
You can use the following macros to perform conditional logging:

```
LOG_IF(INFO, num_cookies > 10) << "Got lots of cookies";
```

The "Got lots of cookies" message is logged only when the variable num_cookies exceeds 10. If a line of code is executed many times, it may be useful to only log a message at certain intervals. This kind of logging is most useful for informational messages.

```
LOG_EVERY_N(INFO, 10) << "Got the " << google::COUNTER << "th cookie";
```

The above line outputs a log messages on the 1st, 11th, 21st, ... times it is executed. Note that the special google::COUNTER value is used to identify which repetition is happening.

You can combine conditional and occasional logging with the following macro.

```
LOG_IF_EVERY_N(INFO, (size > 1024), 10) << "Got the " << google::COUNTER
                                           << "th big cookie";
```

Instead of outputting a message every nth time, you can also limit the output to the first n occurrences:

```
LOG_FIRST_N(INFO, 20) << "Got the " << google::COUNTER << "th cookie";
```

Outputs log messages for the first 20 times it is executed. Again, the google::COUNTER identifier indicates which repetition is happening.

You can check [here](https://hpc.nih.gov/development/glog.html) for more info

Comment: Thank you for your long answer, But the actual business scenario is to record all logs. There may be tens of thousands of logs a day.